# What is best practice for calling async method from Quartz.NET Job Execute?

Tags: c#, .net, quartz.net, quartz.net-3.0

I'm converting previous synchronous Quartz.NET 2.0 jobs to the new async Quartz.NET 3.0 framework and I was curious what the best practice was for dealing with the results of calling another async method that you need the results from?

In my scenario I'm using a package called [CliWrap](https://github.com/Tyrrrz/CliWrap) that is for interacting with command line executables. In my scenario I use their buffered option which captures the stdout and stderr streams into a buffer that you can then inspect.

My question then, is it better to have the Quartz job wait on the result from the CliWrap call (Option 1 below) or is it better to have the job be async as well and assign a JobListener to grab the buffered result when the job completes (Option 2 below)? Thanks

**Option 1**

```
public Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context) {
    MyJobDetails jobDetails = context.MergedJobDataMap["MyJobDetails"] as MyJobDetails;
    var result = Cli.Wrap(jobDetails.ExecPath))
        .WithArguments(jobDetails.Arguments)
        .ExecuteBufferedAsync();
    var r= result.GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    //do whatever with output
    string stdout = r.StandardOutput;  
    return result;
}
```

**Option 2**

```
public async Task Execute(IJobExecutionContext context) {
    MyJobDetails jobDetails = context.MergedJobDataMap["MyJobDetails"] as MyJobDetails;
    var result = await Cli.Wrap(jobDetails.ExecPath))
        .WithArguments(jobDetails.Arguments)
        .ExecuteBufferedAsync();
    //set the result in the context
    context.Result = result;
}


public class SimpleListener : IJobListener {
    public Task JobWasExecuted(IJobExecutionContext context, JobExecutionException jobException, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default(CancellationToken)) {
        var result = (BufferedCommandResult)context.Result;
        //do whatever with output
        string stdout = result.StandardOutput;            
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should almost never use `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` in any context. You are blocking the thread with `GetAwaiter().GetResult()` and it will waste the whole purpose of `async` and  `await`.

You should go with Option 2.

Comment: Yeah I guess that's the way to look at it. It's just weird because their documentation has that Execute method defined with or without async which I don't understand? Because if I use await then it will just continue to run asynchornously and then return control to that block when it completes right?